# Django Template Syntax error: Could not pass the remainder

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a Django project and I am relatively new to the Django framework. After running the application using `python3 manage.py runserver` I am getting an error like `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '['role']' from 'session['role']'`.
This is the particular html file to which the error is pointing.
base.html

```
{% block body %}
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %} "id="icon" alt="User Icon" width="30" > {{ application.name }}</a>
          {% if session['role'] == "manager" %}
# rest of code
```

How do I get this done with? please help

Comment: Can you add the view that renders this html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this in the Django template

try this

```
{% block body %}
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %} "id="icon" alt="User Icon" width="30" > {{ application.name }}</a>
          {% if session.role == "manager" %}
# rest of code
```

Please refer this  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/